# React native not running on localhost

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native

React native stopped working, whenever I run it now (no matter which project) I get the error could not connect to development server |
ensure the following
node server is running and available on the same network - run npm start from react native root.

Node server url is correctly set in appdelegate

URL : http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle? platform=ios&dev=false

Comment: Could you open the file in a browser, if your server is started? Whether through Xcode run or `npm start`?

Comment: I uploaded my operating system and the problem magically disappeared, no idea what the problem was, thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure you have done the following

1) run server using

```
npm start
```

2) if you are using actual device , make sure you are connected to same network

3) for android: run the following command and try again

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Answer (score 1):

I was face same problem while running in physical device.

I did as below:

1. Open terminal and check your local ip address.
2. Shake device(android) click on dev settings
3. Click "Debug server host & port for device" under debugging
4. type local ip address and port number.

note: cross check in browser ip along with port number.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just run npm start in my terminal. (OSX) I assume it would be the same on Windows

```
npm start
```

Comment: I have osx and it doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

To debug on a real device:

1. On iOS - open the file AppDelegate.m and change localhost to the IP address of your computer. Shake the device to open the development menu with the option to start debugging.

   ```
   let jsCodeLocation = NSURL(string: "http://{{YOUR IP ADRESS}}:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios")
   ```
2. On Android, you can open dev menu on the device and select Dev Settings, then update Debug server host for device setting to the IP address of your computer.

Comment: My IP address changes, do I need to update that everytime?